# Changing the dupplicated name of the sequence generator in already existing entities

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I had a JPA-entity Bar in which a sequence generator was declared com.foo.IdGenerator. Then I copied this entity, corrected it a bit and created a second Buzz entity. The problem is that I forgot to change the name of the generator in the second entity and now they duplicate each other in both entities. There were no problems with the work of the application. But in the log the following errors are issued

`[WARN][main] 05 Dec 2022 09:09:09,992 [o.h.b.i.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl] 242093 HHH000069: Duplicate generator name com.foo.IdGenerator`

Now I want to rename these sequences to com.foo.bar.IdGenerator and com.foo.bar.Id Generator.

Will this somehow affect the work of my application with Hibernate and the database?

I only want to change the name of the sequence generator, not the name of the sequences themselves. The sequence names for both entities are unique.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bar")
public class Bar {
    private static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "bar_sequence";
    private static final String SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME = "com.foo.IdGenerator"; // I want to change it to com.foo.bar.IdGenerator

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Buzz")
public class Buzz {
    private static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "buzz_sequence";
    private static final String SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME = "com.foo.IdGenerator"; // I want to change it to com.foo.buzz.IdGenerator

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question and concern. Do you have this deployed in production - have two entities using the same sequence generator? Are you looking to now change it without affecting your production environment adversely? IF so, you'll need to check the last sequence value used for the entity you want to use the 'new' sequence and be sure to set the sequence to that value, otherwise it will hand out values that are already in use.

Comment: @Chris you're not quite right. I don't want to change the sequence in entities. The sequences is correct. I want to rename the sequence generators in the annotations _GeneratedValue and _Sequence Generator.
I checked after renaming how the process of assigning an id occurs when creating new entity instances. Sequences seems to be fine. The id increment occurs as before.

But I do not know if there could be any other effects from changing the name of the sequence generator.

Comment: Again, I do not understand. The name you are changing is in the annotations and only assigned the sequence for the entity to use. If they were using the bar_sequence generator - they were using the same sequence. The 'buzz_sequence' wasn't being used and remained at the initial value while the table that should have been using it was getting assigned sequence values from the shared one. It will give out 1 as the first value to insert. If that isn't an issue, there is no issue at all - it is just a name to point JPA at a specific sequence generator you can define anywhere.

Comment: @Chris Strange... the bar_sequence and buzz_sequence sequences have different values. They are not shared between tables. That is, if I understand you correctly, if there are no problems in set id through the use of sequences, then there will be no another problems with this?

Comment: As long as the current sequence value in each is greater than the max ID value in the table that will use the sequence, there isn't an issue.